# Vim user-defined command filter

Tags: vim

I have the following input file:

```
abcde                                                                         
abc                                                                      
abcdef                                                                   
abcd
```

that I would like to sort by line-length. I can do this by running the command `1,4!awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n -s | cut -d' ' -f2` which gives the output:

```
abc                                                                      
abcd                                                                     
abcde                                                                    
abcdef
```

Now I want to create a user-defined command `SortL` that will do exactly the same as above:

```
command! -count SortL <count>!awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n -s | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

However when I run `1,4SortL` on the input file I get:

```
abcde                                                                         
abc                                                                      
abcdef                                                                   
abcd
```

no changes were made so I must have made a mistake on the definition of `SortL`. How  to define `SortL` so that lines get sorted by length?

Comment: see `:h command-range`. What you try to pass is a range, not a count. So it is `-range` not `-count` and `<line1>,<line2>` instead of `<count>`

Comment: Awesome this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness, the answer to this is:

`command! -range SortL <line1>,<line2>!awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n -s | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Answer (score 1):

Note that it can also be done in vimscript only, which has the advantage of being portable (given it's run from vim -- OK, lambda are quite recent, they are 2 years now?)

```
command! -range=% SortL 
   \ call setline(<line1>, 
   \              sort(getline(<line1>,<line2>),
   \                   { a, b -> strchars(a) - strchars(b)}))
```

BTW, `strchars()` will correctly count the number of glyphs in multi-bytes characters, and not the number of bytes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get error 121: `Undefined variable: a`. Also I'm not familiar with *lambdas*...  could explain what they are?

Comment: [Lambdas](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#lambda) have been introduced in Vim 7.4.2044. If your version of Vim isn't recent enough, this won't work. Instead, you'll need to define a function and pass its [_Funcref_](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Funcref) to [`:sort()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#sort%28%29).